# Asymptotical convergence of the Likelihood ratio test in general hypotheses testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, asymptotics, likelihood-ratio, bayes-factors

I'm aware that the 2-loglikelihood ratio is asymptotically distributed as a Chi-squared distribution under the Null hypotheses for nested hypotheses. My question is, there is any generalized formula for the asymptotical convergence of the -2LR for any hypotheses test?

I found this paper: Likelihood Ratio Tests for Model Selection and Non-Nested Hypotheses Author(s): Quang H. Vuong but my goal is to obtain an approximation similar to the one in Wilk's theorem that can allow me to say that the quantity is bounded (it's a PDF)

Let $H_0: Y \sim f_0(y|\theta_0)$ vs $H_1: Y \sim f_1(y|\theta_1)$ where $k_0 = \dim(\theta_0)$ and $k_1 = \dim(\theta_1)$. We have that the BIC approximation of the Bayes factor is
$$B_{01} \approx \frac{f_0(\textbf{y}|\hat{\theta}_{0})}{f_1(\textbf{y}|\hat{\theta}_{1})}\cdot(n)^{(k_1 - k_0)/2}$$

Then for separated models, with the same number of parameters, we have that $k_1 = k_0$
and the BIC approximation becomes

$$B_{01} \approx \frac{f_0(\textbf{y}|\hat{\theta}_{0})}{f_1(\textbf{y}|\hat{\theta}_{1})}$$

Now I need to consider the limit as the sample size goes to infinity of this expression, but now this doesn't directly depend only on the samples $y$ that will grow. I would like to obtain a formula that can go to 0 if $H_1$ is the best model and to $\infty$ if $H_0$ is the best model.

Comment: Note that it isn't the likelihood ratio $\mathcal{L}$ that is asymptotically $\sim \chi^2$, it's $-2 \ln \mathcal{L}$.  This leads you to deal with sums over the observations (in most cases) rather than products, which helps a lot with the asymptotics.

Comment: True, I will edit my question thanks for the remark.

Comment: By "any hypothesis test" do you mean non-nested hypotheses?

Comment: something general that work for both